# jcarousel for continous moving of images

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I am using [jCarosel](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) plugin of slider.In this there are buttons of next and previous.When I click on buttons images moves but I want when I keep click on button images continously moves instead of one by one click.

Please give me solution.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I read documentation but there was no option?

Comment: This one http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc?

Comment: @putvande yes but there is no option of keep press an button and images moving instead of one by one click.

Comment: I think it is something you have to change in the Plugin itself in order for it to work. It triggers the function onClick so you need something with `mousedown` and `mouseup`.